# How do I use most_common in a Python counter?

Tags: python, counter

I have a function that aims to give me the bottom n percent occurring words from my data. This function is:

```
def bottomnpercent(table,n):

words=0
wordcounter=Counter()
for key, data in table.scan():
    if not key in stopwords:
        words+=1
        wordcounter[key]+= getsomedata 
        idx=percentage(n,words)
return Counter(wordcounter.most_common()[-idx:])
```

(table.scan loops though an HBASE table that has a word and a frequency count; getsomedata does a lookup that returns the count for a particular word).

The problem is this returns a counter of the form:

```
Counter({('stopped', 173): 1, ('thrilling', 17): 1, ('fluids', 18): 1, ('Pictures', 18): 1, ('steering', 37): 1,...
```

which is no good as everything occurs 1 time and I need something like:

```
 Counter({('stopped'): 173, ('thrilling'): 17, ('fluids'): 18, ('Pictures'): 18, ('steering'): 37,...
```

but I cannot figure out how. Any help is much appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of that  `wordcounter` is a  counter ( `wordcounter=Counter()`) and again you use it inside another counter `return Counter(wordcounter.most_common()[-idx:])` ! you just need to return the following :

```
return wordcounter.most_common()[-idx:]
```

Comment: Duh! That solved it. Many thanks, I will accept this in 10 minutes.

Comment: By 10 mins obviously I meant a week.